# UML diagrams required to generate code (reverse engineering)

Tags: uml

I do know member may say this is same question but here my intention is to know the real **people who used it**, I don’t want any link to tool, I just need to know w**hich are the UML diagrams required to generate code..thats it**

I have seen probably read and hear many things about **reverse engineering with UML**. As far as I understand: UML diagrams transform probably **generate basic code for you** (may be with single click). I am just wondering whether it’s REAL? Anyone has used it? Which are the tools we need to look and probably best to use?

Answer (score 1):

We use only class and state diagrams to generate code.  See http://www.state-machine.com/ in addition to Enterprise Architect mentioned in the other post.

Answer (score 0):

This Stack Overflow question seems to be duplicate to your question [Is there a MDSD/MDA success story for a real world application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096702/is-there-a-mdsd-mda-success-story-for-a-real-world-application)

There are 54 questions in the [mda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mda) Stack Overflow tag that you may find useful

On one project **we used class diagrams and deeply nested state diagrams** to generate both structural and behavioral backbone of our C++ application using the [Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/search/search.pl?Terms=code+engineering&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) and its code engineering and MDG (Model Driven Generation) technologies.

Their [MDA Tool for Model Driven Architecture](http://www.sparxsystems.com/platforms/mda_tool.html) was not available at that time.

For an example of what the tool can do with otherwise just pictures (e.g. Visio treats UML models as just pictures) look at 20 minutes long video webinar `Simulation and Prototyping in Enterprise Architect`at http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/webinar/webinar-series.html